# Raspberry Pi - Tensorflow lite - turn stepper motor when specific class is detected

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to run a stepper motor for 8.5 revolutions (3400 steps) when a certain object class is detected (class = 1 - which is "Person").

I'm using a Raspberry Pi and L298N to interface with a 42BYG stepper motor.

Apologies in advance, my level of Python knowledge is about 0 and my only programming skills date back to the late 1980's Commodore 64 BASIC ;)

I got Tensorflow lite running and managed to re-train the model and use the following code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import io
import re
import time

from annotation import Annotator

import numpy as np
import picamera

from PIL import Image
from tflite_runtime.interpreter import Interpreter

CAMERA_WIDTH = 640
CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480


def load_labels(path):
  """Loads the labels file. Supports files with or without index numbers."""
  with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    labels = {}
    for row_number, content in enumerate(lines):
      pair = re.split(r'[:\s]+', content.strip(), maxsplit=1)
      if len(pair) == 2 and pair[0].strip().isdigit():
        labels[int(pair[0])] = pair[1].strip()
      else:
        labels[row_number] = pair[0].strip()
  return labels


def set_input_tensor(interpreter, image):
  """Sets the input tensor."""
  tensor_index = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['index']
  input_tensor = interpreter.tensor(tensor_index)()[0]
  input_tensor[:, :] = image


def get_output_tensor(interpreter, index):
  """Returns the output tensor at the given index."""
  output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()[index]
  tensor = np.squeeze(interpreter.get_tensor(output_details['index']))
  return tensor


def detect_objects(interpreter, image, threshold):
  """Returns a list of detection results, each a dictionary of object info."""
  set_input_tensor(interpreter, image)
  interpreter.invoke()

  # Get all output details
  boxes = get_output_tensor(interpreter, 0)
  classes = get_output_tensor(interpreter, 1)
  scores = get_output_tensor(interpreter, 2)
  count = int(get_output_tensor(interpreter, 3))

  results = []
  for i in range(count):
    if scores[i] >= threshold:
      result = {
          'bounding_box': boxes[i],
          'class_id': classes[i],
          'score': scores[i]
      }
      results.append(result)
  return results


def annotate_objects(annotator, results, labels):
  """Draws the bounding box and label for each object in the results."""
  for obj in results:
    # Convert the bounding box figures from relative coordinates
    # to absolute coordinates based on the original resolution
    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = obj['bounding_box']
    xmin = int(xmin * CAMERA_WIDTH)
    xmax = int(xmax * CAMERA_WIDTH)
    ymin = int(ymin * CAMERA_HEIGHT)
    ymax = int(ymax * CAMERA_HEIGHT)

    # Overlay the box, label, and score on the camera preview
    annotator.bounding_box([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])
    annotator.text([xmin, ymin],
                   '%s\n%.2f' % (labels[obj['class_id']], obj['score']))


def main():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
  parser.add_argument(
      '--model', help='File path of .tflite file.', required=True)
  parser.add_argument(
      '--labels', help='File path of labels file.', required=True)
  parser.add_argument(
      '--threshold',
      help='Score threshold for detected objects.',
      required=False,
      type=float,
      default=0.4)
  args = parser.parse_args()

  labels = load_labels(args.labels)
  interpreter = Interpreter(args.model)
  interpreter.allocate_tensors()
  _, input_height, input_width, _ = interpreter.get_input_details()[0]['shape']

  with picamera.PiCamera(
      resolution=(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), framerate=30) as camera:
    camera.start_preview()
    try:
      stream = io.BytesIO()
      annotator = Annotator(camera)
      for _ in camera.capture_continuous(
          stream, format='jpeg', use_video_port=True):
        stream.seek(0)
        image = Image.open(stream).convert('RGB').resize(
            (input_width, input_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        start_time = time.monotonic()
        results = detect_objects(interpreter, image, args.threshold)
        elapsed_ms = (time.monotonic() - start_time) * 1000

        annotator.clear()
        annotate_objects(annotator, results, labels)
        annotator.text([5, 0], '%.1fms' % (elapsed_ms))
        annotator.update()

        stream.seek(0)
        stream.truncate()

    finally:
      camera.stop_preview()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

I also got the stepper motor properly running and by using this script:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time 

out1 = 13
out2 = 11
out3 = 15
out4 = 12

i=0
positive=0
negative=0
y=0



GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(out1,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(out2,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(out3,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(out4,GPIO.OUT)



try:
   while(1):
      GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
      GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
      GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
      GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
      x = input()
      x = int(x)
      if x>0 and x<=400:
          for y in range(x,0,-1):
              if negative==1:
                  if i==7:
                      i=0
                  else:
                      i=i+1
                  y=y+2
                  negative=0
              positive=1
              #print((x+1)-y)
              if i==0:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==1:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==2:  
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==3:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==4:  
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==5:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==6:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==7:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              if i==7:
                  i=0
                  continue
              i=i+1


      elif x<0 and x>=-400:
          x=x*-1
          for y in range(x,0,-1):
              if positive==1:
                  if i==0:
                      i=7
                  else:
                      i=i-1
                  y=y+3
                  positive=0
              negative=1
              #print((x+1)-y) 
              if i==0:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==1:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==2:  
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==3:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==4:  
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.LOW)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==5:
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==6:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              elif i==7:    
                  GPIO.output(out1,GPIO.HIGH)
                  GPIO.output(out2,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out3,GPIO.LOW)
                  GPIO.output(out4,GPIO.HIGH)
                  time.sleep(0.001)
                  #time.sleep(1)
              if i==0:
                  i=7
                  continue
              i=i-1 


except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Is there any easy way to take the object class and tell that if class 1 is detected the motor should turn for a specified number of turns?

I tried some if arguments, but guess my Python knowledge is just not up to scratch to solve this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and make the stepper motor code into a function.

```
def stepper_motor_turn(degrees, direction):
    ....
```

Then in the detector code it should be something like this

```
results = detect_objects(interpreter, image, args.threshold)
if <'results is equal to class 1'> :
    stepper_motor_turn(...., ....)
```

This is ofcourse only some pseudo code but seeing the code you already produced you should be able to get something like this working.

The results are a list (a python kind of 'array') of multiple single result values. You can iterate through the results with 'for'. Each single result is a dictionary for each found class id. The values inside the dictionary you can access with their key name.

```
results = [{'bounding_box': array([0.23692542, 0.17234364, 0.7129105 , 0.49806836], dtype=float32), 'class_id': 71.0, 'score': 0.4140625},
           {'bounding_box': array([0.03008232, 0.04455566, 0.97868216, 0.8292703 ], dtype=float32), 'class_id': 81.0, 'score': 0.40234375}]

wanted_class_id = 71.0
wanted_minimal_score = 0.41   # or max ???

......
......
......

for result in results:
    if result['class_id'] == wanted_class_id:
        if result['score'] >= wanted_minimal_score:
            # turn motor
```

Comment: Thank you Mace. I’ll give that a crack and see how I go.

Comment: The results form detect_objects return something like this:

    [{'bounding_box': array([0.23692542, 0.17234364, 0.7129105 , 
    0.49806836], dtype=float32), 'class_id': 71.0, 'score': 0.4140625}, 
    {'bounding_box': array([0.03008232, 0.04455566, 0.97868216, 
    0.8292703 ], dtype=float32), 'class_id': 81.0, 'score': 0.40234375}]

I tried to write an if statement to execute the stepper function when 'class_id' is of a certain value, but that doesn't seem to work since 'results' returns multiple values? I can't seem to figure out how to do that?

Comment: Added some explanation. I hope it helps.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Nice project: pi, motors, ai... :-)) seems like fun.